# Error serving large files when using Flask and Tornado

Tags: python, flask, tornado

I am serving large static files ~70 MB, I am able to download the files when working in flask alone, but I am getting the error below when using Tornado and flask.

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method Future.__del__ of <tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x32c61acc>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/user/virtual/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 333, in __del__
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/traceback.py", line 181, in format_exception
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/traceback.py", line 153, in _format_exception_iter
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/traceback.py", line 18, in _format_list_iter
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/traceback.py", line 65, in _extract_tb_or_stack_iter
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/linecache.py", line 15, in getline
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/linecache.py", line 41, in getlines
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/linecache.py", line 126, in updatecache
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/tokenize.py", line 437, in open
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open'
```

Here is the code that I am using to serve files

```
def download(path):

    def generate():
        with open(path, 'rb') as file_handler:
            while True:
                chunk = file_handler.read(1024)
                if not chunk:
                    break
                yield chunk
    return Response(generate(), direct_passthrough=True, mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                    headers={'Content-Disposition': 'attachment;filename={}'.format(os.path.basename(path))})

http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(APP))
http_server.listen(PORT, address='0.0.0.0')
IOLoop.instance().start()
```